# error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'set<int>'

Tags: c++, constructor, stl, set, size

In C++, I've included the `set` library:

```
#include <set>
```

I would like to create a set with a number of elements equal to that of another set. So, I tried this:

```
set<int> ret((int)ring.size());
```

However, I am getting this error:

```
error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'set<int>'
```

Any idea how can I specify the size of the set from its declaration?

Comment: A std::set is an ordered container usually implemented with a tree. Think about it.

Comment: And what values should be in the set?  It can't initialize them all to zero like `vector(size_t)` would, since that would just result in a one-element set.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Any idea how can I specify the size of the set from its declaration?

You do **not**.

You either copy your old set to the new one, thus populating the set, which results in its size to be increased accordingly, or you insert *unique* values to it, until it reaches the desired size.

You can always check the constructors available in the [ref](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/set/).

---

Think about: Assume a constructor like the one you describe exists. It would have to default initialize the set's values. But that means that all values are the same. That should result in a set with size 1.

Answer (score 1):

That's not entirely logical. You don't reserve storage for elements in a `set` as you would do for other container types, e.g. `vector`. Furthermore all the elements in a `set` must be distinct, so you can't set the elements to the same value.

The number of elements in the `set`, is solely driven by the elements in the set. If you want a set with the same number of elements as another set then you may as well use the *copy constructor*.

Comment: I would rather say "You don't resize a set as you do it with other containers". Reserving size for a set could make sense under certain circumstances (even though `std::set` has no `reserve`). On the other hand resizing a set (to a bigger size) never makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

`std::set` is designed to **store unique elements**.

If that:

```
set<int> ret((int)ring.size());
```

would have been possible it would implicitly assume that you want to create a container storing non-unique elements. Therefore it's not possible (that's what `std::multiset` is used for).